# How can onAuthStateChanged implement in service and use it every pages(components)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can i use onAuthStateChanged in service for use every component ?

I normally used this on all pages.But now I want to call this from the service and I don't want to see **null** when I refresh the page. How can I do this?

```
this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
if(user){

}
else{}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to see null when I refresh the page.

That's unfortunately not going to work.

When you reload the page, Firebase needs to check with the server whether the user account/token is still valid and this takes some time. So when you attach your listener before the token is checked, it will immediately be called with `null` to indicate no user is signed in yet. Then if/when the re-authentication of the user completes, your callback will be called again with the `user` object of that user.

There is no way to change this behavior.

If you want to be able to distinguish between:

1. No user has ever signed in on this device.
2. A user is signed in before, and we're re-verifying their credentials.

One trick is to store a small value in local storage in the browser when the user signs in. Then when the page is restored, you can read that value - and use that to determine whether you're dealing with case #1 or case #2.